# Java: Merge code

Tags: java

I know Objective-C, but I'm trying to write server side code and need help:

[Here is the Code to Fetch an Object by Field](https://github.com/stackmob/stackmob-customcode-java-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackmob/example/CRUD/QueryByField.java)

[Here is the Code to UPDATE the Object.](https://github.com/stackmob/stackmob-customcode-java-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackmob/example/CRUD/UpdateObject.java)

[Here is the Code to CREATE an Object.](https://github.com/stackmob/stackmob-customcode-java-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackmob/example/CRUD/CreateObject.java)

[Here is the Code to DELETE the Object.](https://github.com/stackmob/stackmob-customcode-java-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackmob/example/CRUD/DeleteObject.java)

Currently I have to make 4 API calls to do the above individually.  I would like to make one API call and accomplish all three actions in one code:

I have two `Schemas`:

1. `Cars`
2. `CarsResolved`

I need to do the following:

1. I would like to fetch an Object in `Cars` with `"car_ID"` in the Database (ds).  `"car_ID"` is passed in from the `User`.
2. Next update the field `"resolved"` with an int `"1"`; `"originalID"` with `"car_ID"` in the fetched object. After copying the value of `"car_ID"` to `"originalID",` I would like to like to set the `"car_ID"` to empty or `NULL`.
3. Next I would like to save the updated object in `CarsResolved` Schema.
4. Delete the object that was fetched from `Cars` Schema.

[Incase needed, here is more info on Custom Code.](https://developer.stackmob.com/customcode-sdk/developer-guide#Datastore)

How do I perform all three actions in one code with one API Call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write out the commands that perform each operation one at a time, then you put them all within one method.

--- update to give fictional example ---

```
public void updateUserAgeByName(String name, int age) {
  User user = fetchUserByName(name);
  user.setAge(age);
  updateUser(user);
}
```

another example could be

```
public void updateUserByName(String name, User newValues) {
  User user = fetchUserByName(name);
  user.setAllFrom(newValues);
  updateUser(user);
}
```

there are infinite variations, depending on what facilities are available to you, what you intend to accomplish, and how you structure your code.  There is no "right" answer, but there are answers that are better than others, depending on the patterns of usage and other requirements that need to be met.

Comment: Thanks.  Putting them in one method is what I would like to do, but don't know how.  i.e. Once I have the Object, how do I access that object's Keys and Values?  and over ride them?

Comment: I updated the answer, hopefully it will help you a bit.